# Automate SQL Server imported Data Set Refresh via Powershell script in Visio

Tags: sql-server, powershell, refresh, visio

I'm currently trying to write a Powershell script that I can use to refresh the data in a Visio file and export the results to pdf. The issue I'm running into is that the DataRecordset.Refresh method seems to cause a pop up for credential entry, before it will allow the script to finish. Is there any way around this?

```
$floorplans = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.vsdx"
Write-Host "Converting Visio documents to PDF..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

try
{
$visio = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$visio.Visible = $false

foreach ($floorplan in $floorplans)
{
    


    $pdfname = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($floorplan.FullName, '.pdf')
    Write-Host "Converting:" $floorplan.FullName "to" $pdfname
    $document = $visio.Documents.Add($floorplan.FullName)
    
    foreach($dataSet IN $document.DataRecordSets())
    {

        $dataSet.Refresh()
    }
    # Export all pages to PDF, see constants here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766893.aspx
    $document.ExportAsFixedFormat(1, $pdfname, 1, 0)
}

}

catch
{
Write-Error $_
}

finally
{
if ($visio) 
{
    $visio.Quit()
}

}
```

Comment: As you have noted. This is not a PowerShell code issue, it's a Visio interop one.  If that Visio has been configured to require a password for whatever, then you have to provide the creds. Thus you need to use sendkeys or other GUI automation tool like AutoIT.

Comment: Do you know how to configure visio to save the credentials and not ask for credentials on refresh? That feels like its the missing piece to the puzzle. The reason I proposed it as a powershell issue, is I thought maybe Refresh needed to be used in conjunction with something else.

Comment: Never really tried, so not off the top of my head. Once you are in COM, is all COM, and not really PowerShell. Doing this refresh stuff is making a call to whatever is required, and if auth is involved, there is no getting around that without changing what is asking for it to not ask for it. So, if Visio is calling to some other thing, to get stuff, that other thing could be the cause of this auth prompt in concert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data source requires authentication (credentials) then you need to specify those or save them in Visio file. There is usually a checkbox to allow saving credentials in file (in Visio), on the database connection page, depends on your database type.

Also, you could try specifying the password by altering the connection string, like this:

```
$cs= $dataSet.DataConnection.ConnectionString
$dataSet.DataConnection.ConnectionString = "$cs;password=<your password>"

$dataSet.Refresh()
```

Here is a somewhat related blog article, check it out:
http://ton.snoei.net/2009/08/03/systeem-en-softwaremonitoring-met-visio-2007-4-van-4-de-software/

Please note that you may need a different syntax, depending on the database you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I'm looking for